# $\epsilon$-chromatic number of manifolds

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory, metric-spaces, manifolds, coloring

We consider a homogenous metric space $M$ whose induced topology is a manifold (homogenous meaning the isometry group of $M$ acts transitively). We let the $\epsilon$-chromatic number of $M$, or $\chi_\epsilon(M)$, be the chromatic number of the graph with vertex set the points in $M$, and where two vertices are adjacent iff their distance is $\epsilon$ under our metric.

Intuitively, it feels as though for sufficiently small $\epsilon$ the $\epsilon$-chromatic number of a given space is dependent on the local rather than global properties of the space. Thus, since a manifold approximates $R^n$ locally, I would expect the $\epsilon$ chromatic number to be equal to the chromatic number of $R^n$ for sufficiently small $\epsilon$.

Formally, I ask whether for a given $n$-manifold $M$ induced by a metric as above, is $\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\chi_\epsilon(S) = \chi(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

The reason I require homogeneity is because otherwise there could perhaps be points on our surface around which the largest Euclidean neighborhoods are arbitrarily small, meaning even for a small fixed $\epsilon$  the $\epsilon$ distance graphs near certain such points may have very different behavior to unit distance graphs in the plane. However, its entirely possible that this homogeneity requirement is actually not necessary, as I am basing a lot of this on my (very possibly flawed) intuition.